# What is the natural action of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ on $\mathbb{C}[G]$?

Tags: representation-theory, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra. What is the natural action of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ on $\mathbb{C}[G]$? It seems that the natural action comes from the following. We have a natural comultiplication $\mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes \mathbb{C}[G]$. If we choose a natural pairing $U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes \mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}$, then we have a map 
$$
U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes \mathbb{C}[G] \to U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes \mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C} \otimes \mathbb{C}[G] = \mathbb{C}[G].
$$
I think that this map is an action. What is the natural pairing $U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes \mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}$? Are there some references which give explicit formula for the map $U(\mathfrak{g}) \otimes \mathbb{C}[G] \to \mathbb{C}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is the algebra of left invariant (scalar) differential operators on $G$, hence it acts on $\mathbb{C}[G]$ in the obvious way.

Comment: My favorite references for this topic are Section I.3 of Armand Borel's book _Linear Algebraic Groups_, or Chapters 9 and 10 of James Humphreys' book _Linear Algebraic Groups_. (These books deal primarily with algebraic groups over fields of positive characteristic, but for the question you're asking about, the story will be the same for complex Lie groups.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is making things too hard.  This is the same as a $\mathfrak g$ action on $\mathbb C[G]$, which is given by differentiation by right invariant vector fields.  Extending to $U(\mathfrak g)$ is given by taking the associated differential operator.  The pairing you want is applying this operator and then evaluating at $e$.